# Scroll bar not working with my JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jscrollpane, jtextarea

I have written a basic swing code in which I have wrapped a `JTextArea` into a `JScrollPane`. But still, the scroll bars won't show up even if the text area content goes out of visible `JFrame` area.

The code is as follows -

```
public class TestArea {
    private JTextArea area;
    private JScrollPane scroll;
    private JFrame frame;

    public TestArea(){
        frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
        area = new JTextArea();
        area.setEditable(false);
        scroll = new JScrollPane(area);
        frame.getContentPane().add(scroll);
        area.setLayout(new BoxLayout(area, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
        area.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 10, 10, 10));        
        area.setBackground(Color.WHITE);        
        addMessage();

    }

    private void addMessage() {
        area.add(new JLabel("Can you see me..... can you see me"));
        for(int i=0; i<30; i++){
            area.add(new JLabel(Integer.toString(i)));
            System.out.println(Integer.toString(i));
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }       
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new TestArea();
    }
}
```

The reason for using `BoxLayout` is that I strictly want the output to be aligned in y axis. Here is the link to the output screenshot https://app.box.com/s/rgeyajgvk0ppude399my
As you can see, the scroll bars are not appearing. Can anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 3):

- JTextArea couldn't be container for JComponents, JLabels in this case
- JTextArea is designated for plain text

---

- use JPanel as contianer for arrays of JLabels instead of JTextArea

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was using JLabel because in between I intend to display strings in a different color. Now I will have to look how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> I was using JLabel because in between I intend to display strings in a different color

Then you should probably by using a JTextPane. It supports attributes (like bold, font, color) for each text string you add to the text pane.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on Text Component Features for more information and examples.